# How to find numbers that are both triangular and tetrahedral?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the Wikipedia article on [Tetrahedral number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number) the statement is made that, "Numbers that are both triangular and tetrahedral must satisfy the binomial coefficient equation:    T r n = ( n + 1 2 ) = ( m + 2 3 ) = T e m

Can anyone provide a more complete explanation of why this is true?  Thx!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: triangular numbers are $\binom {n+1}2$ and tetrahedral numbers are ${m+2} \choose 3$

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492356/why-are-0-1-10-120-1540-7140-the-only-triangular-tetrahedral-numbers) is the next question along these lines

Answer (score 1):

If a number is triangular, it can be represented by $\binom {n+1} 2$ for some $n$.

If a number is tetrahedral, it can be represented by $\binom {m+2} 3$ for some $m$.

Therefore, if a number is both triangular and tetrahedral, it is $\binom {n+1}2=\binom{m+2}3$ for some $n$ and $m$.