# (Why) are $0, 1, 10, 120, 1540, 7140$ the only triangular tetrahedral numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, oeis, triangular-numbers

I recently came across entry [A027568](https://oeis.org/A027568) of the OEIS, which reports the numbers
$$0, 1, 10, 120, 1540, 7140$$
as the set of integers which are both triangular and tetrahedral; that is, each can be written as both $\binom{n+1}{2}$ and $\binom{m+2}{3}$ for integers $m,n$. But the entry is not explicit about whether these are the only such integers or merely the only known examples. So, the question: Are these known to be the only triangular tetrahedral numbers, and if so how?

Comment: It's an elliptic curve and these are the only integral points on that curve. It can be easily calculated by a computer algebra system.

Comment: That OEIS page contains a link to the paper, by Avanesov which contains a proof that there are no other.  That paper is in Russian, though perhaps a translation can be found online.

Comment: A discussion in English  can be found [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-227/S0025-5718-99-01047-9/S0025-5718-99-01047-9.pdf).

Comment: The OEIS entry includes the keyword _full_ which means the complete sequence is given, so OEIS is explicit that these are the only such integers. See https://oeis.org/wiki/Keywords